# How to use GuideLine in ConstraintLayout with Kotlin Anko layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, anko

**Question 1:**

While I use `guideline` in ConstraintLayout, it doesn't work at all, the code below cannot set the `orientation` (Why there is no such property?) of `guideline`, which is useless:

```
constraintLayout {            
    guideline {
         //here, cannot set the orientation of guideline
    }
    //...
}
```

Even though the code below can set the guideline orientation, but it still has the same problem with the layout(I don't know whether the guideline is created or not):

```
constraintLayout {            
    constraintSet {
         create(ID_GUIDELINE, VERTICAL_GUIDELINE)
    }
    //...
}
```

So, what is the right way to use GuideLines in ConstraintLayout layout in Anko?

**Question 2:**

ConstraintLayou in another ConstraintLayout may have the unexpected behavior while use `Fragment`.

I use ConstraintLayout(named with **A**) in `Activity`, and ConstraintLayout(**B**) in `Fragment`, then add or replace the **B** into/with **A**, the result shows the width of **B** is always incorrect.

However, if there is a `RecyclerView` in **B**, and set the `layoutParams` of **B** as below:

`layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)`

then it works correctly, without `RecyclerView` but only other widgets, like `buttons/textviews/imageviews`, it shows that the width of **B** is very narrow.

Of course I can change the layout **A** to a `FrameLayout`, but that is not what I want, so why and how to do that?  Thanks for reply!

Also, I have opened the issue in Anko kotlin library here: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/579, and code:

```
// A in Activity
constraintLayout {
    fitsSystemWindows = true
    id = A
}
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(A, fragmentB).commit()
//supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(A, fragmentB).commit()

// B in Fragment
constraintLayout {
    fitsSystemWindows = true
    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 try something like this:

```
    guideline {
      id = ID_GUIDELINE
    }.lparams(0, 0) {
      orientation = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.VERTICAL
      guideBegin = dip(80)
    }
```

Question 2 should be in a separate post with a good title so it's more likely to be answered and is more easily searchable by others.

Comment: Thanks very much ,I have  I have solved this problem, just set the LayoutParams in the item view of RecyclerView: ·layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)·